# Encryption decryption AES for all type of file in java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

how to modify this AES encryption code so that it can encrypt and decrypt any type of file (pdf, docx....), because when I decrypt a pdf file or other I don't get the original file.

```
public EncryptData(File originalFile, File encrypted, SecretKeySpec secretKey, String cipherAlgorithm) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException{
    this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherAlgorithm);      
    encryptFile(getFileInBytes(originalFile), encrypted, secretKey);
}

public void encryptFile(byte[] input, File output, SecretKeySpec key) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    this.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    writeToFile(output, this.cipher.doFinal(input));
}
public SecretKeySpec getSecretKey(String filename, String algorithm) throws IOException{
    byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
    return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, algorithm);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, Exception{
    StartEncryption startEnc = new StartEncryption();
    File originalFile = new File("file.docx");
    File encryptedFile = new File("EncryptedFiles/encryptedFile");
    new EncryptData(originalFile, encryptedFile, startEnc.getSecretKey("OneKey/secretKey", "AES"), "AES");
}
public DecryptData(File encryptedFileReceived, File decryptedFile, SecretKeySpec secretKey, String algorithm) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    decryptFile(getFileInBytes(encryptedFileReceived), decryptedFile, secretKey);
}

public void decryptFile(byte[] input, File output, SecretKeySpec key) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    this.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    writeToFile(output, this.cipher.doFinal(input));
}
public SecretKeySpec getSecretKey(String filename, String algorithm) throws IOException{
    byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
    return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, algorithm);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, Exception{
    StartDecryption startEnc = new StartDecryption();
    
    File encryptedFileReceived = new File("EncryptedFiles/encryptedFile");
    File decryptedFile = new File("DecryptedFiles/decryptedFile");
    new DecryptData(encryptedFileReceived, decryptedFile, startEnc.getSecretKey("DecryptedFiles/SecretKey", "AES"), "AES");
    
}
```

Comment: General purpose encryption algorithms like AES don't care about the kind of document they're encrypting; they just operate on byte streams. If you're not getting the original document after decryption, there's probably a bug in the encryption/decryption code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some important information regarding your source code is missing (method writeToFile, no information about the cipherAlgorithm, no information about the used key) **your code is not executable**.

Therefore I'm providing a sample program to encrypt and decrypt any kind of files using the AES mode ECB.

**Security warning: do NOT use AES ECB Mode in production because it is UNSECURE !** It's better to use a mode like AES GCM.

Provide the filenames for the original file (plaintextfile), the encrypted file (ciphertextfile) and the decrypted file (decryptedfile) and
run the program - the decrypted file is equal to the original file.

I'm using a static key (32 byte/256 bit key length) for this example - to run this program you need the unlimited crypto policies enabled on your Java system.

That's the result:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62883618/encryption-decryption-aes-for-all-type-of-file-in-java
AES ECB Stream Encryption
* * * WARNING Do NOT use AES ECB mode in production as it is UNSECURE ! * * *
file used for encryption: plaintext.pdf
created encrypted file  : plaintext.enc
created decrypted file  : plaintext_decrypted.pdf
AES ECB Stream Encryption ended
```

The code:

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class AES_ECB_Stream {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62883618/encryption-decryption-aes-for-all-type-of-file-in-java");
        System.out.println("AES ECB Stream Encryption");
        System.out.println("* * * WARNING Do NOT use AES ECB mode in production as it is UNSECURE ! * * *");
        String plaintextFilename = "plaintext.pdf";
        String ciphertextFilename = "plaintext.enc";
        String decryptedtextFilename = "plaintext_decrypted.pdf";
        byte[] key = "12345678901234561234567890123456".getBytes("UTF-8"); // 32 byte = 256 bit key length
        encryptWitEcb(plaintextFilename, ciphertextFilename, key);
        decryptWithEcb(ciphertextFilename, decryptedtextFilename, key);
        System.out.println("file used for encryption: " + plaintextFilename);
        System.out.println("created encrypted file  : " + ciphertextFilename);
        System.out.println("created decrypted file  : " + decryptedtextFilename);
        System.out.println("AES ECB Stream Encryption ended");
    }

    public static void encryptWitEcb(String filenamePlain, String filenameEnc, byte[] key) throws IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filenamePlain);
             BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filenameEnc);
             BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out)) {
            byte[] ibuf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(ibuf)) != -1) {
                byte[] obuf = cipher.update(ibuf, 0, len);
                if (obuf != null)
                    bos.write(obuf);
            }
            byte[] obuf = cipher.doFinal();
            if (obuf != null)
                bos.write(obuf);
        }
    }

    public static void decryptWithEcb(String filenameEnc, String filenameDec, byte[] key) throws IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filenameEnc);
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filenameDec)) {
            byte[] ibuf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            while ((len = in.read(ibuf)) != -1) {
                byte[] obuf = cipher.update(ibuf, 0, len);
                if (obuf != null)
                    out.write(obuf);
            }
            byte[] obuf = cipher.doFinal();
            if (obuf != null)
                out.write(obuf);
        }
    }
}
```